# materializecss modals integration into meteor

Tags: meteor, materialize

I am using the official Materializecss package for meteor.The materialize modals are working fine but my problem is that when a add a button into the model and route it to another page, the modal leaf-overlay still remains there.
Is there a way to remove this problem or make materialize reactive with meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to close it programmatically, as shown in the docs, when you redirect (probably right before):

```
$('#modal1').closeModal();
```

Answer (score 0):

On other page rendering:

```
 $('#modal1').closeModal();
```

[Document](http://materializecss.com/modals.html)